# 301 redirect .htaccess parameter php?fr_xyz to php?en_xyz

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

1st i have to say: i tried google of course. so many tips about my request - but i dont get it. maybe you can help...

it sounds simple: i want a 301 via .htaccess to a another parameter file
for example:

www.mydomain.tld/ runs without .htaccess to www.mydomain.tld/index.php?de_xyz
but:
what i want is, if you call www.mydomain.tld you get to www.mydomain.tld/index.php?en_xyz

-> ?de to ?en

if i try a simple: Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.mydomain.tld/index.php?xyz i get a redirection error on this side.

i have tried so many ways. dont get it :/

thx for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)en_xyz(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?en_xyz [L,QSA,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?en_xyz [R=301]
```

Note that 301 is a permanent redirect so the browser might not re-read your configuration if you redirect to a wrong address by mistake while trying.

If not working you might want to add

```
RewriteLog "/some/path/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

to your vhosts file if you have access (it might not work in .htaccess) and get the details from log.

By the way I'd prefer handling this in index.php:

```
header('Location: index.php?en', true, 301);
```